# How to convert a JavaScript file into an abstract syntax tree

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a JavaScript file which I need to parse and find errors in that. To do so I am planning to convert into an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST), so that I can parse through the nodes.

Can anyone suggest to me how to convert JavaScript into AST?

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/acornjs/acorn

Some other parsers are mentioned in https://astexplorer.net — try to change the parser settings and follow the link in the upper right corner.

Comment: acorn requires a node environment to run (npm install), 
do you know of any javascript parser i can use client-side in-browser (e.g let import parser from 'parser-url' )

Comment: @chris Sorry, I do not(